# kendo grid paging does not work

Tags: php, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, paging

How do I assign rows number in total property in kendo grid? I used json to fill the data:

```php
if ($result = mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {   
    while($obj = mysqli_fetch_object($result)) {
        $arr[] = $obj;
    }
}
echo "{\"list\":" .json_encode($arr). "}";
```

But paging does not work with total = total or function !
I don't know where is my grid problem!!

```
$(document).ready(function () {
                var record = 0;
                var grid = $("#grid").kendoGrid({

                    dataSource: {
                        transport: {
                            read: {
                                url: "<?php echo $path?>/contractors.php?m=read&f=subcat",
                                dataType: "json"
                            }
                        },
                        schema: {
                            data: "list",
                            model: {
                                id: "id",
                                fields: {
                                    company: { type: "string" },
                                    firstname: { type: "string" },
                                    lastname: { type: "string" }

                                }
                            },
                            total: function (response) {
                                return $(response.data).length;
                            }

                        },
                        pageSize: 20,
                        serverPaging: true
                    },
                    pageable: true  ....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I see in your code, `total` function should be:

```
total: function (response) {
    return response.list.length;
}
```

What you are returning from PHP is a JSON object that includes an `array` in a field called `list` and this is a JSON object (once in KendoUI `total`). So, the reference to the array is `response.list` and the length `response.list.length`.

Comment: Thanks, it's work but just show number and the grid does not load by pageSize! what do I have to do?